# Python, conditional use of a decorator (package not installed in all env)

Tags: python, decorator, newrelic

I am using New Relic to monitor my Python (2.7) app, but only in my Production environment. I want to use their function_trace decorator.

In wsgi.py

```
try:
    import newrelic.agent
    newrelic.agent.initialize('/path/')
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

In views.py

```
if settings.ENV == "test":
    pass
else:
    import newrelic

@newrelic.agent.function_trace()
def my_function():
    ....
```

This works great in Production, but fails in Test, of course. I can't put if-else directly around a decorator so I was thinking that I could use a conditional decorator:

```
def newrelic_conditional_decorator(function)
    # What magic goes in here...
    if settings.ENV == "test":
        just return function
    else:
        use @newrelic.agent.function_trace() decorator

@newrelic_conditional_decorator
def my_function():
    ....
```

I'm always a bit hazy on decorators so am hoping for some help here! (Or another way to handle not having the same package in Test as in Production.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A decorator takes in a function and returns a new function from it. So if you want a conditional decorator, all you need is to return the initial function when you do not want the decorator to be applied.

## Your specific case

```
def newrelic_conditional_decorator(function):

    if settings.ENV == "test":
        # We do not apply the decorator to the function
        return function
    else:
        # We apply the decorator and return the new function
        return newrelic.agent.function_trace()(function)

@newrelic_conditional_decorator
def my_function():
    ...
```

## A bit of generality

You could abstract this to make a more general conditional decorator which applies a given generator provided some `condition` function returns `True`.

```
def conditional_decorator(decorator, condition, *args):

    def wrapper(function):
        if condition(*args):
            return decorator(function)
        else:
            return function

    return wrapper

@conditional_decorator(
    newrelic.agent.function_trace(),
    lambda settings: settings.ENV != "test",
    settings)
def my_function():
    ...
```

Comment: Tried the specific case and it's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad to read that. Note that I did not include it in the answer, but if as your title states the newrelic package is not installed in your test env, you could import it only in the else clause of the decorator.